# Rails How to use has_many_and_belongs_to_many with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, nested-attributes

I have two models:

Routes and Activity

I have a Many-To-Many relationship between them through a migration that looks like:

```
class ActivitiesRoutes < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
        create_table :activities_routes, :id => false do |t|
            t.integer :route_id
            t.integer :activity_id
        end
    end
end
```

In a rest service i get the data for a route and I get multiple activities, my models look like this:

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :activities_attributes
  has_and_belongs_to_many :activities
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :activities
end
```

and:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :activitytext, :iconid
  has_and_belongs_to_many :routes
end
```

On my app controller I want to make something like :

```
ruta=Route.create({
    #other data for the model
})
ruta.activities_attributes = @activitiesarray #Array made with the Activities received
```

But I get an error:

```
undefined method `activities_attributes' for #<Route:0x2bccf08>
```

If i left it like :

```
ruta.activities_attributes << @activitiesarray
```

I get:

```
undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #<Activity:0x6af7400>
```

Does anyone know ho can I make that possible?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this

```
ruta.activities_attributes << @activitiesarray
```

because `accepts_nested_attributes_for` only provides a `*_attributes=` method so the following should work

```
ruta.activities_attributes = @activitiesarray
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed a correction on the question, when I left it with '=' I get: undefined method `activities_attributes' for #<Route:0x2bccf08>
Updated the question :)

Comment: now that you mentioned it, you are using habtm which is not going to work with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Comment: Could I use has_many and :through and create a join table instead of a migration?

Comment: yes, you *should* use has_many through when you are going to add more details in the join table.  you should also use a migration to create the join table.